# Why is progressive measurability needed here?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Karatzas & Shreve proposition 2.18 says that if $(X_{t},\mathcal{F}_{t})$ is progressively measurable and $T$ is a stopping time w.r.t $\mathcal{F}_{t}$, then $X_{T}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{T}$-measurable. The proof follows by noticing that $\{X_{T} \in B\} \cap \{T\leq t\} = \{X_{T \wedge t} \in B\} \cap \{T\leq t\}$, which is $\mathcal{F}_{t}$-measurable. But I don't understand where progressive measurability comes into play here?

Comment: How do you show that $\{X_{T\wedge t} \in B\} \in \mathcal F_t$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If we denote the mapping $(s,\omega) \rightarrow X_{t}(\omega)$ from $([0,\infty),\Omega)$ to $\mathscr{B}([0,\infty), \mathcal{F})$ by $\phi$, and $\phi ^{-1}(B) = (A,E)$, where $A \subset [0,\infty), B \subset \Omega$, then $\{\omega: X_{T\wedge t}(\omega) \in B\} = {A \cap E}$?

Comment: So you are using progressive measurability. Measurability of $\phi$ is precisely progressive measurability.

Comment: I see! But is the form of $\{X_{T\wedge t} \in B\} $correct??